# What creatures cannot be blinded?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warlock, conditions, eldritch-invocations, blind

Warlock with Beshadowed Blast can blind targets if target fails to make a DC check against
10 + Spell level (4) + Caster level

Beshadowed Blast indicates:

> This eldritch essence invocation allows you to change your eldritch blast into a beshadowed blast. Any living
> creature struck by a beshadowed blast must succeed on a Fortitude save or be blinded for 1 round.

And blinded creatures are:

> The character cannot see. He takes a –2 penalty to Armor Class, loses his Dexterity bonus to AC (if any), moves at half speed, and takes a –4 penalty on Search checks and on most Strength- and Dexterity-based skill checks. All checks and activities that rely on vision (such as reading and Spot checks) automatically fail. All opponents are considered to have total concealment (50% miss chance) to the blinded character. Characters who remain blinded for a long time grow accustomed to these drawbacks and can overcome some of them.

What sort of creatures does not need to make this save since they can't be blinded?

Comment: You are right! Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any creature that either does not have a blind penalty already or the specifically states that it does not use vision as a sense can be blinded. For example, the [grimlock](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/grimlock.htm) notes that it is already blind, so it could not be affected by blindness.

Comment: Honestly, blindness is such an amazing debuff that in my campaigns most intelligent creatures make themselves immune to it—by ECL 10 at the latest—with the purchase of *goggles of the golden sun* (*MIC* 205) (4,000 gp; 0 lbs.) or a *raptor mask* (210) (3,500 gp; 0 lbs.).